# Winter18 upgrade

Tags: pre-release

I got a quick question. Recently my sandbox was upgraded to winter 18 release but last week I refreshed it from Production after one of my production release. This refresh move this sandbox again to Summer 17 release. Is there any way I can upgrade this sandbox back to Winter18 release?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link for details.

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/08/salesforce-winter-18-sandbox-preview-instructions.html

Looks like you are in a non-preview instance and will have to wait till October 13 OR October 14, 2017.

To confirm, it would be best to connect with your salesforce support team though.

Cheers
Sree

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).